# org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: Migration from Java8 to Java17

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, dom, soap

We have two application which serve some purpose
One application is Desktop UI application based on Eclipse GUI - using Java8 & Eclipse Ganymede
Second Application which is recently migrated from - Java8 to Java17 and Springboot2.7 to Springboot3.2

Second application serve multiple purpose and its connect with the DB and get DB through SOAP API ,now Desktop application call SOAP API from the SpringBoot application and rendered data into Desktop application.

Everything was working fine and we were able to get data but after migration to latest version of Java17 and Springboot ,SOAP API is failing and i am getting below exception

> org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create
> or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to
> namespaces.

Code Snippet

```
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = Constants.Namespace.Internal, localPart = "loginRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestPayload LoginRequest request)
            throws PasswordExpiredFaultException, LicenseFaultException, LoginFaultException {
        try {
            return loginProcessor.process(request);
        } catch (CatalogAPIException catAPIExp) {
            if (catAPIExp.getMessage().equals(localeService.getMessage("security.password.expired"))) {
                throw new PasswordExpiredFaultException(localeService.getMessage("security.password.expired"));
            }else if (catAPIExp.getMessage().equals(localeService.getMessage("security.invalid.username.password"))) {
                throw new LoginFaultException(localeService.getMessage("op.security.invalid.username.password"));
            } else if (catAPIExp.getMessage().equals(localeService.getMessage("security.account.locked"))) {
                throw new LoginFaultException(localeService.getMessage("op.security.account.locked"));
            } else {
                throw new LoginFaultException(catAPIExp.getMessage());
            }

        }

}
```

Previously used `spring-ws-core` **3.1.1** updated to **4.0.8** . No any
XML changes done .

Comment: The documentation says you cannot CHANGE a namespace.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/library-change-rules  The XML may already contains a namespace.  You are adding a namespace loginRequest to the root that may exist.  Often the namespace versions are upgraded.  Make sure your namespaces are at the correct version.

Comment: This is a working code upto the time i didnt updated Java version and Springboot version. If i am not adding in root-element calling SOAP API throwing Transport error 404  .

Comment: A bug in library may of been corrected.  Why do you need to add a namespace when the namespace already exists in the xml?

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your reply,i tried to remove from `@PayloadRoot(namespace = Constants.Namespace.Internal, localPart = "loginRequest")` and make it like this   `@PayloadRoot(  localPart = "loginRequest")`  then SOAP API call throwing error 404.

Comment: Error 404 is a credential issue unrelated to your original error.  The namespace issue is solved.  Login is probably working unless the route is bad for the login.  Usually error 404 has to do with the route not being accessible to the credential.  What line of code is failing?

Comment: In this case request only not reaching the SOAP API call..I have added debug point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jdweng . Somehow i manage to fix the issue .
As stated in my question, we recently completed a migration from Java 8 to Java 17 and upgraded our Spring Boot version from 2.7 to 3.2. This migration entailed a significant amount of code changes, including a substantial modification to the SOAP response handler.
Previously we are using code like this

```
SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
SOAPHeader soapHeader = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader();
SOAPElement element1 = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(new QName(Constants.WS_ADDRESSING, "Action", Constants.WSA));
```

But now QName class is not available in Java17 so i modified the code like this

```
SOAPHeader soapHeader = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader();
SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
Name headerElementName = soapEnvelope.createName(Constants.WS_ADDRESSING, "Action", Constants.WSA);
SOAPElement element1 = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(headerElementName);
```

Now above code was creating the issue because of this line

```
Name headerElementName = soapEnvelope.createName(Constants.WS_ADDRESSING, "Action", Constants.WSA);
```

If we check the official definition of this method its something like this

```
Name jakarta.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope.createName(String localName, String prefix, String uri)
```

and i was passing wrong argument here so i have to use this method like this

```
Name headerElementName = soapEnvelope.createName("Action", Constants.WSA,Constants.WS_ADDRESSING);
```

Which fixed the issue.

Just fyi...

```
String WSA = "wsa";
String WS_ADDRESSING = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing";
```

`javax.*` to `jakarta.*` migration is a big impact in the project.

Comment: This looks like a schema issue.  The wsa namespace changed.  I'm not sure why removing the namespace caused the 404 error.